# Crypto Encryption Path

Tags: php

i want to do crypto encryption in php but with the help of cryptoj.jar & one encyption class of java

i have encyption code that is work properly if i put my necessary jar file & java class in the following path

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

This is not an issue for local site, but this is not good idea to put libraries on this root on server.

If i created new directory & put this directory in project folder, the code is not work

i am doing the following code on server.

```
$path = 'java -cp ' . dirname(__FILE__).'/cryptoj.jar; EncryptURLParams "source=BAClubs&identifier=123456&timestamp=2014-02-21 09:59:37.498" ';
echo $path; exit;
    $last_line = exec($path , $retval);
    echo "XCODE=".$last_line; exit;
```

This code returns me nothing but if i put this on rootpath it gives me output. what is the problem guys..?

Comment: Why do you use Java for this? PHP's `mcrypt` might be able to do the job!

Comment: @ThiefMaster i have this requirement & i know mcrypt but i have to go by this way only buddy

Comment: A requirement like this without any reason behind it is stupid.

Comment: i have all reasons to do like this, you only provide the answer, no need to know the reason

Comment: So you rather stay with a crappy solution instead of allowing people to help you properly?

Comment: Why is it not a good idea to put libraries on this root on server?

Comment: on the staging server many projects are available so that is not good idea to put on outside the project folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my answer by myself only

just have to put the libraries in th project's root folder & then simple use the following code

```
$path = 'java EncryptURLParams "source=BAClubs&identifier=123456&timestamp=2014-02-21 10:00:00';
$last_line = exec($path , $retval);
echo "return value--".$retval."<br/>";
echo "XCODE--".$last_line;
```

i got my output in $last_line variable.

Thanks Guys...